# iPhone is displaying weird time 9:41

Tags: iphone, time

My iPhone 5S with 9.1 is displaying `09:41` when it's actually 18:29 local time.

It doesn't seems to be a time channel problem 9:12 is a weird difference (I'm currently in GMT+1).

Comment: I've noticed this also happens when using Quicktime to play iDevice audio through the computer, per http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/192910/5029. The time at the top of the displays changes to 9:41, and the phone service provider's logo changes to a wifi symbol.

Answer (score 6):

EHHHH was connected to my Mac with the video stream launched in QuickTime (my iPhone was the input).

9:41 is the "famous" time displayed during the keynotes :)

Quitting the video stream solves the problem.

Comment: Nice find! 09:40 is 'one more thing' time!

Comment: But why ? Why is it stuck at 9.41 while video streaming?