# Using a MacBook as a Bluetooth speaker for a Windows PC

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, windows, bluetooth, speakers

I was wondering if it would be possible to use the Apple MacBook or MacBook Pro as a Bluetooth speaker for another computer?

The MacBook could act as a Bluetooth speaker that plays the other computer’s sound, similar to Airplay but from a Window’s computer.

Unlike the the other questions, I actually want the sounds of the Windows desktop to play through a Mac. It’s basically replacing a standard desktop speaker.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I play audio from my iPhone on my Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6173/can-i-play-audio-from-my-iphone-on-my-mac)