# Can I have my iPhone play sound for MacBook?

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, audio, headphones

Say I am playing a video on my MacBook Pro, and I don't want to distract others with the sound. The problem is, I don't have a 3.5 mm Headphone or AirPods at my hand, but I have an iPhone 8 Plus and its EarPods with Lightning Connector. Can I play the sound from the video playing on macOS with the iPhone, preferably without connecting the iPhone to the Mac so that I can plug in the EarPods to the iPhone's socket?

This is basically the reverse of [Can I play audio from my iPhone on my Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/6173/168383)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using an app called [Airfoil.](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/mac/)

Description of Airfoil app:

> Stream any audio from your Mac all around your network. Send music services like Spotify or web-based audio like Pandora wirelessly to all sorts of devices, including the Apple TV, HomePod, Google Chromecast, Sonos devices, and Bluetooth speakers. **You can even send to iOS devices** and other computers.

This supports sending audio to iOS devices and is also available for [Windows.](https://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/windows/)

The corresponding app for iOS to revive the audio is [Airfoil Satelite.](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/airfoil-satellite/id1015554329?mt=8)