# Use iPhone as sound output device for MacBook

Tags: macos, iphone, macbook-pro, mojave

I want to connect headphones to my iPhone (7), and then play all audio from my MacBook (Pro with Retina, 15" Mid-2015), through the headphones connected to my iPhone.

macOS Mojave 10.14.6, iOS 12.4.1

How can I do that?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/348527/can-i-have-my-iphone-play-sound-for-macbook?rq=1

Comment: @ankii Why didn't you mark this as a duplicate of the linked question?

Comment: staying cautious after 8 days flag ban(relevant discussion in chat).. and didnt see hints about third party apps for the same in the question. Should have clarified beforehand @fsb